# What is the detailed procedure of writing data into a distributed table?

Tags: dolphindb

We have quote data of 3000 stocks at a given moment and write them into a distributed table with a COMPO domain (the first level is date and the second level is stock tickers). Please illustrate the detailed procedure of writing data into the distributed table. Which steps are single-threaded and which are multi-threaded?

Answer (score 0):

The data writing process in detail is illustrated as follows:

1. APIs such as DolphinDB GUI and Java API send the write command to the worker of the current datanodes.
2. After receiving the command, the worker analyzes the detailed information (including the partition information) of the distributed table, and groups the data to be written according to the partition schema.
3. The worker requests the controller(master) to lock these partitions after grouping the data.
4. If the partitions are locked successfully, the master will package the data according to the partition on the correspondent node and then send the packaged data to the nodes in parallel.
5. Each node that includes the partition to be written creates a transaction to write data.
6. Once all nodes complete writing data, the “complete” message is sent to the coordinator node.
7. The coordinator will commit the transaction after receiving the “complete” message from all nodes involved.
8. After the transaction is committed, each node summarizes the results and sends them to the node that sent the write command. Then the node will return the final result to API.

Only the step of writing data into each partition is multi-threaded, while all the other steps are single-threaded.